# How to change bordercolor on HTML input-field/checkbox through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a "sign up - login-form in HTML/CSS. I have used regexp for email and password. Now I want to color the border of the input-field and checkbox red when they are wrong. I dont know how to select that specific element and make it red.

**HTML**

```
//I want this element's border color red

<input id="email-input" class="account-input"
 type="text" placeholder="Enter Email"
 name="email" required />


//Checkbox element i want red.

<input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox"
 id="capital" name="cap" value="cap" disabled />
<label for="capital">Capital</label>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
if (counter === 6) {
      storeUserData();
      counter = 0;
      console.log(userArray);
    } else { // If email NOT valid do this
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("capital").style.border = "1px solid red";
      document.getElementById("characters").style.border = "1px solid red";
      counter = 0;
    }
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    result.innerHTML = "wrong format";
    //document.getElementById("email.input").style.border = "1px solid red;";
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? At first glance it seems like this should work unless you conditions(if statements) are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Some elements like `select` and `input type="checkbox"` are hard, if not impossible, to style with regard to many of their styling properties.

I'd suggest you use the common checkbox replacement technique:

```css
input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 14px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:invalid + label { color: red; }

input[type=checkbox]:invalid + label::before {
  border-color: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  content: "✓";
}
```

```html
<input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox"
 id="capital" name="cap" value="cap" required />
<label for="capital">Capital</label>
```

In the example I'm using the `required` attribute to make an unchecked checkbox `:invalid`. Feel free to adjust to your needs, for example with a CSS class instead of `:invalid`.

Answer (score 0):

As connexo mentioned, checkboxes are hard to style and you can replace them entirely. You can also use `outline` if you really want to keep the actual checkbox but style it red.

Personally, I would use a CSS class and the `classList.add` or `classList.toggle` methods rather than styling the elements directly.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('email-input')
input.classList.add('error')

const checkbox = document.getElementById('capital')
checkbox.classList.add('checkboxError')
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
  
.checkboxError {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- I want this element's border color red -->

<input id="email-input" class="account-input"
 type="text" placeholder="Enter Email"
 name="email" required />


<!-- Checkbox element i want red. -->

<input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox"
 id="capital" name="cap" value="cap" disabled />
<label for="capital">Capital</label>
```